# How to get ABI code from contract address without using API providers

Tags: go

As I am fetching ABI information from contract address using EtherScan API using golanguage, but is their any other way to get ABI information without using API Providers

Answer (score 0):

you can use abi files if you don't want to use any API providers other than that there is no other way